# Changing background color of a custom UITableViewCell cell in a plain styled UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am trying to change the background color of a custom `UITableViewCell` in a plain style UITableView.

I've read the other similar questions, and I in my delegate method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

I set `cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor...]`. The problem is this only works for a grouped style `UITableView`.

Note: The reason why I want to do this programmatically and not in my .xib file is because I want different background colors for different cells.

Comment: try changing the color of back ground for content view.           cell.contentView.backGroundColor=[UIColor ...];

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe you can add `cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]` before you set your color.

The reason is that the backgroundview is at the bottom. The contentview is at the top.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you. Any idea what the difference is between cell.backgroundColor and cell.contentView.backgroundColor?

Comment: The cell has two layers.One is backgroundview another is contentview.There are some button gived by apple on backgroundview.If you try tableView.editing = YES you can see delete button. It's on the backgroundview

Comment: Sorry, on a closer look, that didn't work. I did set the cell.contentView.backgroundColor to the color I wanted directly and that did work. So please change your answer to that. Thank you

Comment: Ah, try setting yourtableview.editing = YES when you declare your tableview. just see what happens

Answer (score 1):

Change the color in the following delegate method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (...){
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    } else {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// set selection color
UIView *myBackView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];

myBackView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:0.75 alpha:1];

[cell.contentView addSubview:myBackView];

[myBackView release];
```

like this change every cell as u needed